# create unique id for combination of a pair of values from two columns in a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe of six columns say (col1, col2,...col6). I want to create a unique id for each combination of values from "col1" and "col2" and add it to the dataframe. Can someone help me with some pyspark code on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using `monotonically_increasing_id`(pyspark >1.6) or `monotonicallyIncreasingId`(pyspark <1.6)

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
>>> rdd=sc.parallelize([[12,23,3,4,5,6],[12,23,56,67,89,20],[12,23,0,0,0,0],[12,2,12,12,12,23],[1,2,3,4,56,7],[1,2,3,4,56,7]])
>>> df = rdd.toDF(['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6'])
>>> df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   12|   23|    3|    4|    5|    6|
|   12|   23|   56|   67|   89|   20|
|   12|   23|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|   12|    2|   12|   12|   12|   23|
|    1|    2|    3|    4|   56|    7|
|    1|    2|    3|    4|   56|    7|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+

>>> df_1=df.groupBy(df.col_1,df.col_2).count().withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()).select(['col_1','col_2','id'])
>>> df_1.show()
+-----+-----+-------------+
|col_1|col_2|           id|
+-----+-----+-------------+
|   12|   23|  34359738368|
|    1|    2|1434519076864|
|   12|    2|1554778161152|
+-----+-----+-------------+

>>> df.join(df_1,(df.col_1==df_1.col_1) & (df.col_2==df_1.col_2)).drop(df_1.col_1).drop(df_1.col_2).show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|col_1|col_2|           id|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
|    3|    4|    5|    6|   12|   23|  34359738368|
|   56|   67|   89|   20|   12|   23|  34359738368|
|    0|    0|    0|    0|   12|   23|  34359738368|
|    3|    4|   56|    7|    1|    2|1434519076864|
|    3|    4|   56|    7|    1|    2|1434519076864|
|   12|   12|   12|   23|   12|    2|1554778161152|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Jim. This solves my problem but it is adding duplicate columns. In th above it added col1 and col2 again. How do I remove them?

Comment: Edited my answer. As it is only two columns, I have dropped them from the result.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to generate the unique ID from col1 and col2 you can also create a hash value leveraging the `sha2` function of Spark.

First let's generate some dummy data with:

```
from random import randint

max_range = 10
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
            [(x, x * randint(1, max_range), x * 10 * randint(1, max_range)) for x in range(1, max_range)], 
            ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'])

>>> df1.show()
+---+---+---+
| C1| C2| C3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1| 60|
|  2| 14|180|
|  3| 21|270|
|  4| 16|360|
|  5| 35|250|
|  6| 30|480|
|  7| 28|210|
|  8| 80|320|
|  9| 45|360|
+---+---+---+
```

Then create a new uid column from columns C2 and C3 with the next code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sha2, concat

df1.withColumn("uid", sha2(concat(col("C2"), col("C3")), 256)).show(10, False)
```

And the output:

```
+---+---+---+--------------------+
| C1| C2| C3|                 uid|
+---+---+---+--------------------+
|  1|  1| 60|a512db2741cd20693...|
|  2| 14|180|2f6543dc6c0e06e4a...|
|  3| 21|270|bd3c65ddde4c6f733...|
|  4| 16|360|c7a1e8c59fc9dcc21...|
|  5| 35|250|cba1aeb7a72d9ae27...|
|  6| 30|480|ad7352ff8927cf790...|
|  7| 28|210|ea7bc25aa7cd3503f...|
|  8| 80|320|02e1d953517339552...|
|  9| 45|360|b485cf8f710a65755...|
+---+---+---+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **rank** function.

```
rdd=sc.parallelize([[12,23,3,4,5,6],[12,23,56,67,89,20],[12,23,0,0,0,0],[12,2,12,12,12,23],[1,2,3,4,56,7],[1,2,3,4,56,7]])
df = rdd.toDF(['col_1','col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6'])
df.show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   12|   23|    3|    4|    5|    6|
|   12|   23|   56|   67|   89|   20|
|   12|   23|    0|    0|    0|    0|
|   12|    2|   12|   12|   12|   23|
|    1|    2|    3|    4|   56|    7|
|    1|    2|    3|    4|   56|    7|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

To generate unique id, pass the list of columns in the orderby function of Window

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
df.withColumn("uid", rank().over(Window.orderBy("col_1", "col_2"))).show()

+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|col_5|col_6|uid|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+
|1    |2    |3    |4    |56   |7    |1  |
|1    |2    |3    |4    |56   |7    |1  |
|12   |2    |12   |12   |12   |23   |3  |
|12   |23   |56   |67   |89   |20   |4  |
|12   |23   |3    |4    |5    |6    |4  |
|12   |23   |0    |0    |0    |0    |4  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+
```